# Django Admin list view: add CSS class for rows by field value

Tags: python, css, django, django-admin

Example model:

```py
class Article(models.Model):
    is_published = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Is there an easy way to add "is_published" css class to all  in Django admin list view to all rows displaying objects with is_published==True?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-vs-replacing-an-admin-template - Override the admin template, and add teh custom class there.

Comment: yes, that seems only way, I will try to work with that. I just need to find out how to access is_published field in template (i'm just getting whole <td>...</td> html in result)

Comment: If you're willing to use JavaScript that might be a more elegant solution. Just write a script that scans rows and changes the class based on the value in the cells. You could use `class Media` to add custom js & css for the `ModelAdmin` class.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not quite sure is it what you looking for. The following example displays all "is_published" fields in red font, where "is_published==True"

```
class Article(models.Model):
    is_published = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def colored_is_published(self):
        if self.is_published:
            cell_html = '<span style="color: red;">%s</span>'
        else:
            cell_html = '<span>%s</span>'
        # for below line, you may consider using 'format_html', instead of python's string formatting
        return cell_html % self.is_published   
    colored_is_published.allow_tags = True

class ArticleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = (......, 'colored_is_published')
```

Reference: [Django list display](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display)

Comment: thanks, but this is not enough. I need to highlight whole rows (like row1 and row2 classes)